# Xpath query to find nodes whose descendants contain particular text

Tags: php, xpath, screen-scraping, descendant

Doing some PHP/Xpath coding for some scraping, and I want to know an XPath expression to select nodes which have a parent whose sibling, somewhere in their descendant tree, contain a node with a particular text value.

Say the node is something like span[@ng="league"] and the text value somewhere in a descendant is 'SKT', I believe it should in some way include
contains(text(), 'SKT'), but I'm not quite sure on the rest.  TIA.

[I've tried to create a diagram of the situation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVvWp.jpg)

```
|
+[parent]
|    |
|   [the node I want]
|     
+[sibling of "parent" node seen above]
|   |
|   *
|   |
|   +---[specific text, found with previous xpath query]
|
etc
```

Comment: `//span[@ng="league" and .//*[contains(text(), 'SKT')]]`

Answer (score 3):

The following XPath will return `span[@ng="league"]` elements where there is at least one text node anywhere within the `span` that contain substring 'SKT':

```
//span[@ng="league" and .//text()[contains(., 'SKT')]]
```

If this doesn't work then you need to be more specific i.e post minimal HTML/XML example (formatted text, not image) where the XPath above doesn't return the desired output

Comment: Thank you.  I will give that a try.  Can you point me in the direction of something to read about how to format text for diagrams like that?  I tried it as a code block, but that didn't work.

Comment: The thing is, it's not in the span itself, it's in another span, located in the sibling of the parent of the span.  I will try again, to post a text-diagram

Comment: Looks like you need [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) axis.. Probably : `//span[@ng="league" and .//text()[contains(., 'SKT')]]/preceding-sibling::span[1]`

Comment: @MikeDonovan Instead of diagram, it will be far more useful if you post simplified XML/HTML example. You can say which element exactly you want to get from that example, and we can use it test our XPath before posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your xml is something as

```
<parent>
  <span ng="league">The node you want </span>
</parent>
<any>
    <any2>
       <any3>SKT</any3>
   </any2>
</any>
```

you can use such xpath

```
//span[@ng="league"][../following-sibling::*[contains(., "SKT")]]
```